# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected installation example

Tags: hadoop, installation, giraph

I am running the example from http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html#qs_section_2
After successfully installing Giraph i create file /tmp/tiny_graph.txt  and run

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

I get an error

```
15/03/10 19:38:21 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format specified. Ensure your InputFormat does not require one.
15/03/10 19:38:21 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge output format specified. Ensure your OutputFormat does not require one.
15/03/10 19:38:21 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: Setting custom argument [giraph.SplitMasterWorker] to [false] in GiraphConfiguration
15/03/10 19:38:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.job.counters.limit is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.counters.max
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.map.memory.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.memory.mb
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.user.classpath.first is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.maxattempts
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO job.GiraphJob: run: Since checkpointing is disabled (default), do not allow any task retries (setting mapred.map.max.attempts = 1, old value = 4)
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
15/03/10 19:38:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.giraph.bsp.BspOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(BspOutputFormat.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.run(GiraphJob.java:259)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

My current versions are 
Giraph 1.2.0
Hadoop 2.6.0

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the error log above it seems like uncompatible versions of Giraph,Hadoop and Java. Check if the version you are using is compatible. If you still face error please update POM.xml.

Comment: I cannot find information on version matching should I downgrade GIRAPH ? if so which version specifically?